# Snapsvg transform line

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

When trying to transform line by matrix I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'line'

Here is the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeoyA

When I am trying to do identical transform with different shape, for examlpe circle, it works.
Are matrix transforms not supported on lines? What should be correct way of moving lines then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that's a bug in the library as in SVG lines are transformable. In the meantime you could use a path to create a line.

```
var s = Snap(600, 600),
        line = s.path("M0 0 100 100"),
        matrix = new Snap.Matrix().translate(100, 100);

line.attr({
    stroke: "#F00",
    strokeWidth: 4
});
line.transform(matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks, I created issue on github: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/132